# D3 - Drag selection for multi nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Anybody has implemented a multi selector in D3 ? I mean the selector itself on the SVG.

I would like to draw a drag selection and select all nodes included. See the following picture where the red rectangle with glossy blue would select the nodes it covers.

[image]

There is some math to calibrate the selection but this won't be a problem. I'd like first to build the drag-shade. Anybody does something in the like ?

Comment: https://observablehq.com/@d3/brushable-scatterplot?collection=@d3/d3-brush

Comment: looks very much like what I am looking for thanks.